# output can't be displayed when using string.format to display 2d array

Tags: java, character

```
public class Arr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] arr = new char[4][];
        arr[0] = new char[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
        arr[1] = new char[]{12, 13, 14, 5};
        arr[2] = new char[]{11, 16, 15, 6};
        arr[3] = new char[]{10, 9, 8, 7};
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%s", arr[i][j]));
                if (j == 3) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

When I run the program in eclipse, the output is

Can anybody help to find where the error is?

Comment: Whats the expected output? All of your characters are unprintable.

Comment: I'd assume you want to print numbers, right? In that case better use a numeric primitiv such as `short` or `int` and when printing use the `%d` conversion (most likely you'll want to add some length and padding to your conversion in order to have the numbers nicely aligned - the Javadoc can help you here).

Comment: Simply replace, `String.format("%s", arr[i][j])` to `arr[i][j]`.

Comment: hi thomas, yes, i want to print the numebrs in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(String.format("%s", arr[i][j]));
```

This will print each char as a string using it's unicode value. Consider changing `%s` to `%d` if you want to see the integer output.

This results in the code:

```
System.out.print(String.format("%d", (int) arr[i][j]));
```

Or even better, just use:

```
System.out.print((int) arr[i][j]);
```

This will print the integer value directly.

Your code is printing those wierd squares since those integers map to those values in unicode. Take a look at https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0000 for an idea of the unicode conversion Java uses.

Comment: I tried your code and was getting `Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Character'

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, you have the cast the `char` to an `int` before doing that. Added it now

Comment: Really though, either change the array to the type `int[][]` or just use the the second method I mentioned `System.out.print((int) arr[i][j]);`, which is cleaner than an un-needed `String.format`

Answer (score -1):

If like to print actual character you have to add 48 which is '0' in ASCII, values below 48 are unprintable.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Try this:

```
System.out.print(arr[i][j] + 0);
```

Comment: hi bartek, thank you soo much for your quick reply.....i got the output

Comment: hi.....bartek, i got the output when i used " System.out.print(arr[i][j] -  0);" also.....how is it so?